# React & MUI - How to apply specific MUI theme palette color to fill MUI icon SVG?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, theming

I'm using MUI & REACT for my web application but was wondering how could you fill a SVG with the color value defined in my MUI palette.

My palette looks like this:

```
const theme = createTheme(
    {
        palette: {
            mode: "light",
            primary: {
                main: "rgba(33, 150, 243, 1)",
                dark: "rgb(31,141,229)",
                light: "rgb(35,157,253)"
            },
            secondary: {
                main: "rgba(255, 82, 82, 1)",
                dark: "rgb(232,74,74)",
                light: "rgb(253,92,92)"
            },
            background: {
                main: "hsl(0, 0%, 87%)",
                default: "hsl(0,0%,95%)"
            },
            common: {
                main: "hsl(0, 0%, 96%)",
                white: "hsl(0,0%,100%)"
            },
            text: {
                primary: "#232323",
                secondary: "#444444"
            }
        }
    },
    localsMui[lang]
)
```

And the SVG which I try to apply the color:

```
<LogoutIcon fill="primary.main"/>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

I tried to use useTheme() but it doesn't work either.

Comment: is `LogoutIcon` imported from `@mui/icons-material` or is it custom icon? please specify. if its custom icon then share code of `LogoutIcon`

Answer (score 0):

const theme = useTheme()

Now we need to know what is LogoutIcon component doing with the prop.
It should pass it down to the svg fill attribute. If its not done correctly, you can try

and then use 'currentColor' value for the svg fill attribute.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue but I was trying to set the "primary.contrastText" color of my palette. It looks like it only uses the "primary.main" color if you pass "primary". See the code here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Icon/Icon.js#L54

**For your issue:**

As long as your palette's `primary.main` is the the color you want the icon to be, just pass the prop as `color="primary"`.

**For my issue:**

I had to add a new style rule in my `makeStyles()` custom styling object and pass in the theme and set the icon's color to `theme.palette.primary.contrastText`.

My code looked like this:

```
import {
    DateRange as DateRangeIcon,
} from '@mui/icons-material';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    icon: {
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    },
}));

export default function Component(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <DateRangeIcon className={classes.icon} />
    );
}
```

**Alternate solution to my issue:**

An alternative solution is to add another custom color palette when you make your theme object and under palette do something like this:

```
palette: {
    // your normal color palettes here then..
    myCustomColorForIcons: {
        main: "ACTUAL_COLOR_YOU_WANT",
    }
}
```

Then in your Icon set the "color" prop to be the new color palette's name like this: `<YourIcon color="myCustomColorForIcons" />`